# Unable to install any module in pythonanywhere server

Tags: python-3.x

I am new at pythonanywhere server. I am trying to run my python script on pythonanywhere server but import errors are coming(no module named ...). When I am trying to install the modules, error is coming:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement urllib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for urllib[image].
Also please tell is it a good idea to run your python script on this server?
I need recommendations on how to run your jupyter notebook scripts remotely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

urllib is a builtin module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html), so there is no pip package for it.